# Simplifying logarithmic expression.

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to prove an answer from a book about trigonometric substitution.

The question is $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 -4}}dx$.

According to the book the answer is $\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x^2-4}+2ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-4}|+C $.

I think I'm almost done. I'm ok with the first term which is the $\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x^2-4}$ . I just need to simplify the last part. I got $2\ln|\frac{x}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4}-1}|$ and to simplify further I got $2\ln|\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}|$.

I tried to use some properties of logarithm but it seems I can't simplify it further. I hope you could help me to explain how to simplify it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have already solved it.

If you write the 2nd part as $2ln|\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}| \implies 2ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-4}|-2ln2$ then you can take the $2ln2$ part into the integration constant itself

that simplification is done using the logarithmic identity: $ln\frac{a}{b}=lna-lnb$

Comment: Where does the 2 at denominator goes and where does the $2\ln2$ came from?

Comment: @DonThomasReyes check edit

Comment: Thanks a lot but how about the 2ln2. Is it because it is a constant so it will be part of the $C$ as frog @frog1944 said?

Comment: yeah, any constant can be included in C

Answer (score 0):

From the expression, $2 \ln|\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}| = 2 \ln|\frac{x + \sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}| = 2 \ln|x + \sqrt{x^2-4}| - 2 \ln2$. But that last term, $2\ln 2$ is a constant, thus we can simplify it to $2 \ln|x + \sqrt{x^2-4}| + C$ (which includes the other constant).

Comment: But how it becomes $2ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-4}|-2ln2$. How did you simplify it?